# how to split data table into multiple files based on column file?

Tags: java, xml, database, jdbc

I need to dump a table into multiple xml files based on the specific column value
Eg. 
Table

```
Progressive     ID   Content
1               A    Test1
2               A    Test2
3               A    Test3
4               B    Test1
5               B    Test2
6               B    Test3
7               C    Test1
8               C    Test2
```

my question is i am gonna output this table into xml files based on the value of ID column 
i trying to write an algorithm to do that but i failed to track the ID value 
my pesudo code is

```
tmp_id = ""; 
while (resultset.next()) {
    if(resultset.getString("ID")!=tmp_id){
        create new xml file
        tmp_id =  resultset.getString("ID");
    }
    write the remain data corresponding to same id 
    *****if (current resultset.getString("ID")!= the next resultset.getString("ID")) 
    {
       close the xml file 
    }
}
```

the my main problem is on ***** point where i can't check if the current id is different from the next id or no 
please help me and correct my algorithm 
the out should be like that

```
file1.xml should have 
1               A    Test1
2               A    Test2
3               A    Test3


file2.xml should have 
4               B    Test1
5               B    Test2
6               B    Test3

file3.xml should have 
7               C    Test1
8               C    Test2
```

---

Update the original post to add the current algorithm i am using now to make it easier to understand my question

```
int tmp_blockid = 0;
boolean flagIsOpen = false;
while (rs.next()) {

     //Check if the IDBLOCK is different from the tmp_blockid if yes write new file
     if (rs.getInt("FEIDBLC") != tmp_blockid) {                    
        flagIsOpen = true;
        outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        fileOutputStream = new 
        FileOutputStream(newFile("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\Projects\\"+ "new.xml"));
        writer = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);

        //Method to write the header of the xml
        writeHeader(progrS, rs, writer);
        System.out.println("Start");
        tmp_blockid = rs.getInt("FEIDBLC");
     }

     //Method to write the body of the xml
     writeBody(rs, writer);

     //This is where is my problem this condition should check if the
     //current id different from the next id on the next resultset row but i failed here 
     if (rs.getInt("FEIDBLC") != tmp_blockid) {
         flagIsOpen = false;

        //Method to write the footer of the xml
        writeFooter(writer);
       if (fileOutputStream != null) {
          fileOutputStream.close();
       }
       System.out.println("End");
     }
}
//to close the file in case if the resultset have some rows 
    if (flagIsOpen) {
         flagIsOpen = false;
         writeFooter(writer);
         if (fileOutputStream != null) {
             fileOutputStream.close();
         }                
     }
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one variable (like a Writer) to write to the XML file. Close it directly before you create the new one. After the loop one more close is needed. Be sure, your query orders the record by ID column.

```
tmp_id = ""; 
Writer out = null;
while (resultset.next()) {
    if(resultset.getString("ID")!=tmp_id){ 
        if(out != null) {
          out.close();
        }
        //create new xml file
        out = new FileWriter(...);
        tmp_id =  resultset.getString("ID");
    }
    write the remain data corresponding to same id 
}
if(out != null) {
  out.close();
}
```

Comment: i combined your answer id with my requirement and i get the correct answer which helped me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

the correct answer thanks to @vanje is

```
while (rs.next()) {

     //Check if the IDBLOCK is different from the tmp_blockid if yes write new file
     if (rs.getInt("FEIDBLC") != tmp_blockid) {
     //to close the file in case if the resultset have some rows 
    if (flagIsOpen) {
         flagIsOpen = false;
         writeFooter(writer);
         if (fileOutputStream != null) {
             fileOutputStream.close();
         }                
     }
        flagIsOpen = true;
        outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        fileOutputStream = new 
        FileOutputStream(newFile("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\Projects\\"+ "new.xml"));
        writer = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);

        //Method to write the header of the xml
        writeHeader(progrS, rs, writer);
        System.out.println("Start");
        tmp_blockid = rs.getInt("FEIDBLC");
     }

     //Method to write the body of the xml
     writeBody(rs, writer);


}
//to close the file in case if the resultset have some rows 
    if (flagIsOpen) {
         flagIsOpen = false;
         writeFooter(writer);
         if (fileOutputStream != null) {
             fileOutputStream.close();
         }                
     }
```